# How to get this Json responce in android? i am getting a huge data on server so i want to filter it

Tags: android, json, restful-url

I am getting a Huge Json data from a server,... like [here](http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/?dev=1&slug=android)

but my device is unable to handle those much of JSON data,.. The above one is just Example,...

but i have a Data like,.

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "details": [
            {
                "offers": [{
                    "id": "852255CAG8Qqadsfds4KEw",
                    "price": "99.99",
                    "seller": "google",
                    "availability": "Shipping in two days",
                    "currency": "USD"
                }],
```

Like this but i can this,... but i struk this at,..

```
{
"workind":"ok"
 status: ok
"result": [
    {
        "details": [
            {
                "offers": [{
                    "id": "852255CAG8Qqadsfds4KEw",
                    "price": "99.99",
                    "seller": "google",
                    "availability": "Shipping in two days",
                    "currency": "USD"
                }],
           "getting_responce":ok
           "data"{[
          ] } }
```

like that i am calling results at fist its strucked and i need to call more  like results,.. data,.. process,.. so i am strucking over tehre
any one please help me for the part of retrivel process,... i want to work with this example android code at [here](http://developer-android-tutorial.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-how-to-parse-json-and-show.html)

but over there he is calling "worldpopulation"

Comment: In this format, your question is off-topic on stackoverflow. Take a look at [this topic on help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see how to refine your question. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself."

Answer (score 1):

I think you can parse the complex JSON response using GSON. Please check these tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

You jus create the model classes and use the proper annotations then the data will be parsed to model objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

For a json file as shown below

```
{"success":1,"events":[{"date":"Dec 14","event":"FBC Christmas Banquet \u2013 5PM"},{"date":"Dec 15","event":"Evangelist Allen Domelle in AM & PM Services"},{"date":"Dec 22","event":"Christmas Offering"},{"date":"Dec 23","event":"Nursing Home Christmas at 10 AM"}]}
```

I used parsing like this.

```
try {
                        // Getting Array of Contacts
                        events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENTS);

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for(int i = 0; i <=events.length()-1; i++){
                            JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String event = c.getString(TAG_EVENT).toString();
                            String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE).toString();

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_EVENT, event);
                            map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            eventlist.add(map);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

By looking at your code, you need to call json array thrice as you are having three arrays.

Comment: Let me know if it helped or not.

Comment: yes sir,. this is fine but for a hude amount of different json array and objects,.. that means { a: b: v: 1: {[ a: b: { a: a: {[....]} and what should i call for differnet objects ,... tell me from  a url,..Please help sir,... in android

Comment: @user2967727: Tell me which part of the above json part you need. I will try to get the code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) from Google? it is a easier way to solve your problem and my team use it a lot in our project.I think you can find all you want in gson.

Answer (score 0):

Seperating value from http response:

```
  private void get_dataFromServer(String php) {
    JSONObject jArray = null;
    String responseString = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url ="your url"; 
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        responseString = out.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),responseString,1000).show();

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(responseString);
    int example=integer.parseInt(ja.getJSONObject(0).getInt("YourInteger"));
    }catch(Exception e){

    Log.e("COUNT", "Error in http connection: "+e.toString());
    finish();
    }
  }
```